# Have 4 'ands' in a select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search function on my website with 4 checkboxes. These are then pasted to the next page where I want to find all products which match the criteria of the check boxes.

As I have 4 check boxes I want to use 4 'ands' but I believe 3 is the max (?)

How can I get around this so it searches to see if all products are matched?

HTML Form

---

```
<div id = "search">
            <form name = search action = "search.php" method = "POST">
            <p class = "big"> Refine Menu </p>
            <hr>
            <input type = "text" name = "search" placeholder = "Search for an item" size = "12">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Go"> 
            <br><br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "vegetarian"> Vegetarian 
            <br><input type = "checkbox" name = "vegan"> Vegan 
            <br><input type = "checkbox" name = "coeliac"> Coeliac 
            <br><input type = "checkbox" name = "nutFree"> Nut free 
        </form>
        </div>
```

PHP

---

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}

if(isset($_POST["search"])){
    $search = $_POST["search"];
}

if(isset($_POST["vegetarian"])){
    $vegetarian = 1;
}
else{
    $vegetarian = NULL;
}

if(isset($_POST["vegan"])){
    $vegan = 1;
}
else{
    $vegan = NULL;
}

if(isset($_POST["coeliac"])){
    $coeliac = 1;
}
else{
    $coeliac = NULL;
}

if(isset($_POST["nutFree"])){
    $nutFree = 1;
}
else{
    $nutFree = NULL;
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE vegan = '$vegan' and nutFree = '$nutFree' and vegetarian = '$vegetarian'  and coeliac = '$coeliac'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo $row ["name"];

}
```

I've tried a number of different thing but I don't know the correct syntax for the sql.

NOTE: In my database whether it meets the requierment on it is saved as either a 1 or 0 that is why I changed it from 'on' or 'off'

Comment: .. i dont know where you heard there are at most 3 `and` statements, but it's rubbish. try it. what error did you get? at a cursory glance your statement looks fine. what does your $sql string look like after its created? also, you should look into using prepared statements and bound parameters instead of string concatenation for building your query

Comment: Your SQL query is correct...

Comment: correct your form element <form name = search action = "search.php" method = "POST"> it is  name = "search"

Comment: I have just realised my error. The SELECT statement is now working but the problem was that when I set the else statements to NULL it was setting that to 0 so the correct rows were not selected.

A test row I am trying to retrieve is where all values are set to 1 but the NULL meant that it didn't comply with those conditions

Comment: Slightly different question but how can I set a variable to be either 1 or 0 so in the case of a user not checking a tick box the variable could select any row in the database and that doesn't matter? So where I set NULL in the fields above I sort of need an 'Either is fine' variable

I mistook the NULL values in the SELECT statement with the four conditions to not work but it was in in fact the NULL causing it not to

Comment: if the box isn't checked. don't add it to the query.

Comment: `nutFree = '$nutFree'` won't work as expected when `$nutFree` is `NULL`. NULL is different in SQL: `nutFree IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a large, unmaintainable chain of if statements, you might consider something similar to the following, which will dynamically build up your query depending on which of your required fields have been checked in your form:

```
<?php
   $search_fields = array( 'vegetarian', 'vegan', 'nutFree', 'coeliac', ...);
   $ands = array( '1' => '1');

   foreach($search_fields as $req)
   {
      if(isset($_POST[$req]) && $_POST[$req] != '')
      {
        $ands[$req] = "$req = '1'";
      }
   }

   $and_part = implode(" AND ", $ands);
   $query = "select .... from ... WHERE $and_part  ... ";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. I was mistaken when I posted the question because the reason I thought my sql statement wasn't working was because there were too many ands and I didn't see that rather my sql didn't do what I thought it should.

Here is what I changed it to or it has set values or the check boxes ticked but always the ones which aren't to be either or.

Thanks for everyone's help!

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}

if(isset($_POST["search"])){
    $search = $_POST["search"];
}

if(isset($_POST["vegetarian"])){
    $vegetarian = 1;
}
else{
    $vegetarian = "  ";
}

if(isset($_POST["vegan"])){
    $vegan = 1;
}
else{
    $vegan = "  " ;
}

if(isset($_POST["coeliac"])){
    $coeliac = 1;
}
else{
    $coeliac = "  " ;
}

if(isset($_POST["nutFree"])){
    $nutFree = 1;
}
else{
    $nutFree = "  ";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (vegan = '$vegan' or vegan = 1 xor 0) and (nutFree = '$nutFree' or nutFree = 1 xor 0) and (vegetarian = '$vegetarian' or vegetarian = 1 xor 0) and (coeliac = '$coeliac' or coeliac = 1 xor 0)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row ["name"];
}
```

Comment: I think you're making things complicated without gaining anything. Look at each bracketed subclause in your WHERE statement and see if you can justify having the 'xor 0'. I think the answer offered by @pala_ gives you the best advice, look at what it suggests, and then modify it slightly if you discover that your requirements differ.

Comment: That is the first time I have ever seen `xor` used in a query.  It's really not necessary here either - `1 xor 0` is always 1

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `NULL` have no significance when converted to a string (the SQL query), they will evaluate to empty and your query will look like `nutFree = '' and vegetarian = ''  and coeliac = ''`.

If those fields are `0` in the database, you must set the variables to `0` then.

On a second case, if they are `NULL` in the database, you must change both your query and the way you define `NULL` here.

First, those string wrappers should go away. You don't need them for numbers anyway, those are supposed to wrap strings only:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE vegan = $vegan and nutFree = $nutFree and vegetarian = $vegetarian and coeliac = $coeliac";
```

And then instead of setting the variables to `NULL`, you will set them to the **string**  `"NULL"`.

```
$nutFree = "NULL";
```

This will make `NULL` show on the SQL query as its expected to.